# Как получить содержимое ссылки без title с помощью BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Может вопрос и глупый, но как поступить тут. Есть ссылка:

```
<h1 class="article__headline">
<a href="/">Какой-то текст</a>
</h1>
<span property="dc:title" content="Какой-то текст" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
```

Она без класса и тайтла, как получить из нее "Какой-то текст" с помощью BeautifulSoup? Либо из тега , либо из скрытого спана.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `.article__headline > a`

Comment: Если так делаю, он вообще игнорит заголовки и ошибку...

Comment: Конкретно для куска кода, который вы привели пример сработает. Я дал вам сам селектор, каким образом вы в итоге пытаетесь получить текст?

Comment: Вот так последний раз попробовал:
   name_block = block.select_one('a.article__headline > a')
        if not name_block:
            logger.error(f'no name_art on {url}')

Comment: Если вы хотите вытащить текст, то нужно использовать таким образом - block.select_one('a.article__headline > a').text

Comment: name_block = block.select_one('a.article__headline > a').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Если меняю вот так, чтобы вытащить из h1, то ошибок нет, но и выводит так же ссылку, вместо текста из нее
name_block = block.select_one('h1.article__headline > a').text
А вот как удалось таки, взял тег выше и вытащил из span:
name_block = block.select_one('header.article__header, content')

Comment: Странно конечно, я взял html который у вас в вопросе и предложенный мной способ работает. Зависит конечно правда ли у вас такая структура + код до этого тоже играет роль. Ну ладно, главное что разобрались, успехов.